# C# UWP One MediaElement multiple screens

Tags: c#, uwp, mediaelement

I'm working on simple audio player. So far I was using `BackgroundMediaPlayer`, but it doesn't seem to work, when background audio task is added to application manifest. `MediaElement` works, but needs to be added to XAML tree of a screen. My application has multiple screens, and that is my problem. Is there a way to use `MediaElement` without binding it to any screen, or any way to use it with multiple screens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the `MediaElement` is designed to support audio and video it needs to be attached to the UI so it can actually *display* the video and the media control elements.

If all you are looking for is playing Audio, without requiring user interactions (volume control, play, pause, next, etc.) maybe you can look at other classes like [AudioGraph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs). You can also find a sample [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation).

Comment: Thanks... So UWP has no other option, that **would** allow playback control?

Comment: not that I know of. But since you want it on different pages/windows it cannot have a UI if you want seamless playback right?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in Windows 8.1 where there is no background audio. I solved it by placing the MediaElement to the application frame.

I created a frame style

```xaml
<Style x:Key="RootFrameStyle" TargetType="Frame">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Frame">
                <Grid Background="#F3F2F2">
                    <MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer"
                                  AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia"
                                  AutoPlay="True" />
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and assigned it to the frame when the app starts. The I can get it by

```
DependencyObject rootGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Window.Current.Content, 0);
_player = (MediaElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootGrid, 0);
```